# Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key winRT 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

> This is my xaml.cs file,

```
  public class k_array
    {
        public String Fitment { get; set; }
        public String Part { get; set; }
        public String Nrb { get; set; }
        public String Dimension { get; set; }
        public String No_off { get; set; }

        public k_array(String fitment, String part, String nrb, String dimension, String no_off)
        {
            this.Fitment = fitment;
            this.Part = part;
            this.Nrb = nrb;
            this.Dimension = dimension;
            this.No_off = no_off;
        }

    }

    public class K_arrays : ObservableCollection<k_array>
    {
        public K_arrays()
        {
            Add(new k_array("Michael", "Anderberg",
                    "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45","",""));
            Add(new k_array("Chris", "Ashton",
                    "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67","",""));
            Add(new k_array("Cassie", "Hicks",
                    "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89","",""));
            Add(new k_array("Guido", "Pica",
                    "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10","",""));
        }

    }
```

> And code written in my .xaml code,
>   I have written the textblocks in a Listbox and
>   trying to get the resource from K_arrays from my .cs file

```
<Grid x:Name="listView4">
            <ListView x:Name="testgrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="T1"> </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="T2"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="T3"></TextBlock>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource K_arrays}" Width="350" Margin="0,5,0,10">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Fitment}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nrb}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dimension}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding No_off}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

> Error : Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key K_arrays [Line: 35 Position: 34]
>   I have changed the .cs file also and posted it

Comment: Your code is working properly (as you have written it) - you have defined few *TextBlocks* and every step of your `while` loop change the *Text* property of those *TextBlocks*. You aren't adding any new items/textblocks so the Text is overwritten in every step. At the end you see only the last result. You will probably need to use DataTemplate and create collection of your items - [little help here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265158(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: @Romasz I have changed as you suggested now I am getting this error:Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key K_arrays. How to resolve this.

Comment: It cannot find it because you haven't defined it. Look at that MSDN link and you will see that the key is declared in `<Grid.Resources...`. If you want to follow that example you will also need to do that, also don't forget about the namespace (above `xmlns:src="...`. Note also that's not a good idea to rebuild completely your question and turn into another.